# How to remove previous version from Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have two versions of Julia in my Jupyter. Please see the following picture.
[image: Programming Language Drop-down list]

Julia 0.5.0 is not working, as it shows "kernel error". I want to delete it from the Programming Language Drop-down list. Can anyone tell me how to delete it? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Run `jupyter kernelspec list` on the command line to get the paths of all your kernels.

It would show kernel names like

```
Available kernels:
  julia-1.0    /home/user/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/julia-1.0
  julia-1.1    /home/user/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/julia-1.1
  python3      /home/user/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

And then you can run

```sh
jupyter kernelspec uninstall julia-1.0
```

to remove the old kernel that you want to remove.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this and I get an error saying '[Win Error 5]Access is denied. Perhaps you want sudo?' What do I do? I'm quite new to Julia